# How do I configure and verify my mail is routing between two Administrative Groups in Exchange 2003?

Tags: exchange-2003

I adopted an environment that is having an issue with email routing where emails are delayed due to too many hops.  Some of my users are able to send/receive with no delivery delays, but many of my users are experiencing send/receive delays both internally and externally.

All my email comes through a hosted spam filter, then it's forwarded to us.

Our environment has two Administrative Groups, `CurrentGroup` and `OldGroup`.  These accept emails for multiple domains.  All our emails are supposed to come through `OldGroup`, which has our smart-host (I'm assuming the previous IT team was trying to migrate from one to the other, but never finished the project).

`OldGroup` is connected to `CurrentGroup` using a Routing Group connector with the following servers as remote bridgeheads:

- BACK-END1
- BACK-END2
- BACK-END3
- BACK-END4

`OldGroup` has two SMTP connectors.  The 1st SMTP connector goes to `remote.partner.com` (which is hosted in a different facility); all mail going here is forwarded through the partner's smarthost via public IP, with the local bridgehead `SMART-HOST`.  The 2nd SMTP connector is supposed to route all out-going email using DNS with the local bridgehead `SMART-HOST`.

`CurrentGroup` is also connected to `OldGroup` with a Routing Group connector, with the remote bridgehead `SMART-HOST`.  I made this change last night and it seemed to help, but I'm still having delivery problems.

`CurrentGroup` has one SMTP connector forwarding all mail through the smarthost `SMART-HOST` with the following local bridgeheads:

- BACK-END1
- BACK-END2
- BACK-END3
- BACK-END4

Here is a logical view:
[image]

Here is an example of my Exchange System Manager View:
[image]

On the Default SMTP Virtual Server service for all the servers, I've set up the smart-host value to be `SMART-HOST`.

I believe the problem lies somewhere between the Routing Groups. I'm not sure these are properly configured.  Do I need an SMTP Connector from my `CurrentGroup` pointing to my `OldGroup` through `SMART-HOST`? and from `OldGroup` to `CurrentGroup` through the backend servers?  How do I configure and verify my mail is routing between two Administrative Groups in Exchange 2003?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the following changes:

- Remove any smart hosts set on SMTP virtual servers. Your smart hosts should be set on the *SMTP connectors*, not on the SMTP virtual servers themselves. A smart host set on an SMTP virtual server will cause all traffic sent by that virtual server to be sent to the specified smart host (even if the virtual server is just named in an SMTP connector that has no smart host specified).
- Grab a copy of [WinRoute](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10947) to examine your gateway address routing table (GWART). It will help you visualize what Exchange is trying to do.
- Remove the SMTP connector from the `CurrentGroup' Administrative Group (AG). You don't need an SMTP connector in the`CurrentGroup`AG for email to be delivered from`CurrentGroup`servers to the Internet through the`SMART-HOST`server located in the`OldGroup`AG, so long as the address space on the`SMTP Connector`connector in the`OldGroup` AG isn't scoped to the AG level.

Comment: It turns out I do need the SMTP Connector for the `CurrentGroup` AG.  Thanks again!